# Sampling of image collection

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I have an ImageCollection of Sentinel2 as follows.

```
var Sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                    .filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-12-31')
                    .filterBounds(AOI);
```

From above ImageCollection (Sentinel2) of 100 (suppose) images, I want to randomly sample 10 and output this as ImageCollection of 10 images.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earth Engine is a deterministic programming environment, so only limited forms of pseudorandom numbers are available. One of them is [`ImageCollection.randomColumn`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#ee.imagecollection.randomcolumn), which adds a property with a pseudorandom number to each element of a collection. We can use this to randomly sample by using that as a sort key:

```js
var seed = 328948349;
var tenImages = Sentinel2
    .randomColumn('randomKey', seed)  // 'randomKey' is a made-up property name
    .sort('randomKey')
    .limit(10);
```

(If you wanted to sample from a much larger collection, it might be a better idea to instead filter on the random value being less/greater than a threshold — which should be cheaper than sorting but the exact number of images you get will be random.)

Note that this will return the same collection of images every time, unless you change the seed. If you want a random seed you will have to generate it using JavaScript, before the computation is sent to the Earth Engine servers, such as by:

```js
var seed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1e18);
```

(The multiplication is necessary because `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1, but `randomColumn` wants an integer.)

Comment: thank you. I have a question. Is there any reason to use such a large number for seed `var seed = 328948349`. Cannot it be just as `0` or `1`? `var seed = 0`.

Comment: @mixi I picked a large number just to demonstrate that some number should go there. If you use any specific number — whether that's 0 or 1 or 2185 — then you'll get the same subset every time you use this technique to select some images (regardless of what the images are, as long as the count is the same), and that might be an unintended bias by happenstance, so I think it's a minor good habit to put something _different_ in for the seed, but if there's no concern about correlation with other results then you might as well use 0 all the time.